# How to calculate the proficiency based on an exam with questions of different difficulty levels?

Tags: statistics

In an examination (multiple choice test), suppose there are `n` questions each question can have a difficulty level between `1 - 5` (`1` for the easiest question and `5` for the difficult one).

If someone answers `x` questions correctly and `y` questions wrongly (`x + y = n`) How can we calculate the average difficulty level of a question which s/he can correctly answer?

Comment: We know the difficulty level of each questions.

Comment: Can you track which question is answered correctly or wrongly? Or do we only know the tally?

Comment: Yes we know which question is answered correctly or wrongly. (Even the time spent on the question is available )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so we have question $i$ with difficult level $X_i$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$.

Say the set $S$ is the collection of the question indices of the questions that are answered correctly.

So the average difficulty level of the questions answered correctly, $P$, is
$$P=\frac{\sum_{i\in S}X_i}{\mathrm{n}(S)}$$
where $\mathrm{n}(S)$ is the number of elements of the set $S$.

---

However, if you want the average difficulty earned by the candidate, $Q$, then we consider
$$Q=\frac{\sum_{i\in S}X_i}{n}$$
instead. This means that the candidate will earn $0$ difficulty credit for the question they answer wrong.

---

Using your example in the comment, we will have
$$p=\frac{3+3+3+3}{4}=3$$
but
$$q=\frac{3+3+3+3}{10}=1.2$$

Essentially, you are finding the candidate's score where each question has different weightage.

Comment: consider this example,
Say all the questions are with the difficulty level `3`
 And out of total `10` questions, one answered `4` questions correctly. 
so as per your equation, 
average difficulty = `12/4` = `3`,  but I think actually it should be less than 3 since  he couldn't answer most of the questions correctly.

Comment: @Hrishi oh I get what you want now, I'll add that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, my purpose is to prepare next exam which is appropriate to his level